# render duplicate turn the page reactjs

Tags: redux, reactjs, axios

I have the following code, which loads the information of the current user in the nav bar if the user is logged in or loads empty data if the user has not logged in. The code works for me, but I have a problem: when I go to any other page the nav is duplicated (specifically the `rendernav` function).

`editprofile.js` --> create the dispatch, and load the JSON

```
export const editProfile = (callback) => {
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch({type: 'LIST_USER_REQUEST'});
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/38c1444f753c70cf79ee980638a14de7/raw/34951eebfa006fea3db00fb492b491ac990c788e/vamos.json',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    })
    .then((response) => {
      dispatch({type:'LIST_USER_SUCCESS', payload:response.data});
      if (typeof callback === 'function') {
        callback(null, response.data);
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      dispatch({type:'LIST_USER_FAILURE'});
      if (error.response.status == 401) {
        browserHistory.push('login')
        toastr.error(error.response.message, 'User')
      }
      if (typeof callback === 'function') {
        callback(error.response.data, null)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

`EditProfileComponent.jsx` -->created the component

```
export default class NavComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>SN</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>created</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.renderSign()}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }


        // --> this function duplicated, when I go to another page


  renderSign() {
    return this.props.allProfile.map((profile, index) => {
      if (profile.status === 'SUCCESS') {
        return (
          <ul className="nav navbar-nav" key={index}>
            <li className="dropdown user user-menu">
              <a href="#" className="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <img src="img/perfil.jpg" className="user-image" alt="User Image" />
                <span className="hidden-xs">{profile.user.email}</span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        )
      } else if (profile.status === 'FAIL') {
        return (
          <ul className="nav navbar-nav" key={index}>
            <li><Link to='/sign_in'>Sign In</Link></li>
            <li><Link to='/sign_up'>Sign Up</Link></li>
          </ul>
        )
      }
    }
  }
```

Join the component with the service:

```
import { editProfile } from '../action/editProfile.js';
import NavComponent from '../component/editProfileComponent.jsx';

export default class EditProfileContainer extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.editProfile();
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <NavComponent allProfile={this.props.allProfile} />
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(store) {
  return {
    allProfile: store.allProfile
  };
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {
      editProfile:editProfile
    }, 
    dispatch
  )
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(EditProfileContainer);
```

`editProfileReducer`  --> the reducer

```
export const editProfileReducer = (state=[], action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'LIST_USER_REQUEST':
      return state;
    case 'LIST_USER_SUCCESS':
      return state;
    case 'LIST_USER_FAILURE':
      return [...action.payload];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you intentionally adding more than one <ul> tag in your tbody? Also, shouldn't these be <tr> and <td>??

Answer (score 0):

Even though I don't see the whole code structure, it looks like you are using the wrong reducer. I see that you are using `store.allProfile` when you should be using `store.editProfile`. If the allProfile array has two items then you would have two `<ul>` tags when you use the .map function. If the `allProfile` array was intentionally intended to be used, then you should not use the .map function and instead just use just the first element of the array.

Comment: can you made a example, please